# Design question about instantiating objects in Java

Tags: java

my responses may be slow, but I had a design question I'm hoping to get some advice on:

I'm trying to make a fight simulator for a phone game I play. I have a class representing each hero, which implements their particular abilities' logic. They inherit an abstract Hero class, which itself inherits an abstract Unit class.

The Unit class holds the stats and effects (buff and debuffs), Hero has abstract methods for ability logic, and the individual heroes implement said methods.

Now the part I can't figure out, is I have a very basic GUI, where you can select up to four heroes from drop-down lists. And I need a way to then create the specific hero class objects needed for the rest of my program based on what they select.

But I obviously can't use the dropdown value as a class type, so am I forced to just make some massive switch case for them all or something? Or is there a more elegant method people use that I'm just not thinking of?

There would eventually be over 100 unique heroes (and therefore classes), and I'm just struggling with how to efficiently create objects only for the ones selected in my dropdown menus. Once they're made, I plan to add them to a small array of type Hero (their super class) and then just reference by index going forward.

It's just how to go about filling the array up that's causing me to get stuck.

Sorry for rambling, but hoping that explains things well enough. And just to be clear, I'm writing this all in Java and using JavaFX for the GUI.

Comment: Q: What exactly constitutes a "Hero" ... and why do you need 100++ different class types (presumably [subclasses](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp) of some "Hero" superclass) to represent different kinds of "Heroes"?

Comment: So Hero is my superclass and it's just an abstract to let me identify any of its children as being of that type mainly. And for subclasses, each hero has their own set of moves they can use with independent effects and damage formulas that I need to implement. So my plan is to make each one its own subclass of Hero

Comment: 100 Heroes is a lot to start with (and a lot for an end user to go through). Are you absolutely set on this?

Comment: @JakeF Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: It's based on a game with a couple hundred heros already in it called Epic Seven. I don't intend to actually implement all of them right now, I'm just planning to create a handful and get the actual simulation to work correctly. But I'm trying to figure out how to best future proof it so I'm able to add more in easily over time as they're created.

Comment: What makes a hero unique? What differentiates one hero from the next hero? Can 4 heroes all have the same hero subtype?

Comment: In Java, I'd do this with a `HeroFactory` enum with a `newInstance` method that each value would override or would have a `Supplier<HeroBuilder>` that the enum-wide `newInstance` method would use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I need a way to then create the specific hero class objects needed
> for the rest of my program based on what they select

I don't know if you know SQL, The way that you'd do this using a SQL database is to have 1 table for heroes, 1 table for all hero objects, and then a table that references both a hero and a hero object. Then you could query all the hero objects via

```
select Object from HeroObjectTbl where hero = ??
```

If you don't know SQL, do you know how to use any other database technology? IMO you really need a DB for this

Comment: The only SQL knowledge I have right now is with making basic queries in an already existing DB. I'll try to look into this though and see if I can figure it out, as it does seem like it would be a good way of handling things long term. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Caveat: you might not want to interact with SQL directly.  There are many advantages to using an [ORM](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/orm_overview.htm) like [Hibernate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/) or [ORMLite](https://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) instead.  ALSO: regarding your original question of how to instantiate any one of many different subclasses: consider using a [Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of functions (sort of) in which each function creates a different hero.

```
public interface HeroCreator() {
  public Hero create();
}
```

Then, you instantiate the array in the beginning of your game:

```
  (...)
  public HeroCreator[] creators = {
    new HeroCreator() { 
      @override public void create() {
        return new Hero1();
      }
    },
    new HeroCreator() { 
      @override public void create() {
        return new Hero2();
      }
    },
    (...)
  };
  (...)
```

Finally, you just get a position i from you combobox and call the creator at that position:

```
i = (...)

Hero hero = creators[i].create();
```

Disclaimer: I did not check the code for typos and other errors, but the logic is this.

Comment: I don't know which is more efficient, but this is kind of the idea I had myself, but as a giant switch Statement. I could just match a case based on what they select and have it call the particular class constructor I need and push it onto my array for later use. It just feels clunky to write so much code for that one thing, and wanted to see if there was a more concise way of doing it. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: Or better yet, create an enum. But yeah, this is the way I'd do it too. Enums are a great way to avoid switches (or a less fragile way to implement switches, with compile time failure rather than runtime failure if you forget to add a case).

Comment: @JakeF By efficiency you mean processor time? If yes, then the array is more efficient, because you only need to create it once and then reuse. If your looking concise way, you than use lambda functions to instantiate each hero, but that depends on the java version your are using. Shadow Man also pointed out the use of enuns, which I missed. It seems an elegant solution for the problem.